# serialize two atrribute and convert to json in sortable jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

i got this script:

```
<ul class="draggable-item" style="min-height:10px;">
    <li data-parent="31" data-id="1" class="ui-state-default">Label</li>
    <li data-parent="31" data-id="2" class="ui-state-default">Max Value</li>
    <li data-parent="31" data-id="3" class="ui-state-default">Unit</li>
    <li data-parent="31" data-id="4" class="ui-state-default">Warning Level High</li>
    <li data-parent="31" data-id="5" class="ui-state-default">Warning Level Low</li>
</ul>
```

i want to serialize `data-parent` and `data-id` , then give me JSON object like this after sorting:

```
ex:

{
    "data": [
    {
       "id":"2",
       "parent": "31"
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "parent": "31"
    }
    ]
}
```

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/809/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a2n4o6t7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through the elements to get the attribute values. The following code iterates through the elements and outputs the object.

```
var dataObj = {};
var attribArray = [];
$('.draggable-item li').each(function(el,i){
    var obj = new Object;
    attribArray.push({'id' : $(this).attr('data-id'), 'parent' : $(this).attr('data-parent') })
})
dataObj['data'] = attribArray;
```

Just use JSON.stringyfy to convert it to a JSON String.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimal_Chandrasiri/GCu2D/810/)